# Can we deactivate a flow from managed package?

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, deactivate

I have **a flow** in my managed package, which I do not need anymore.

I know that **we can not delete it from a managed  package** (without connecting to Salesforce Support).

Howevere maybe someone know how we can ***deactivate*** it in installed orgs ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, flows will always be deployed/installed as active on package installation. Same for Process Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Flows are deployed as active per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_manage_install.htm&type=5). What you can do to help eliminate the actions that the flow take is to remove all activity from it so that it simply doesn't do anything.